# Is there a better way for me to time events in C#?

Tags: c#

I declared the following variables:

```
    private Stopwatch stopwatch;
    private long t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
```

and I am using Stopwatch like this:

```
         try {
            stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            get1();
            t1 = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            anotherGet();
            t2 = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            vm.Detail = anotherAnotherGet();
            t3 = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
        } finally {
            Stopwatch.Stop();
            if (vm.Detail.Count() > 0) {
                return PartialView("Details", vm);
            } else {
                return Content("No records found");
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way I could store my times rather than in
longs named 1-5. The problem is that in some areas of 
code I might only need t1 and in other areas I might need 
more than 5 timing points.

I am using a finally for stopping. Is that the correct way to
do this?

Comment: You should use `vm.Detail.Any()` instead of `vm.Detail.Count() > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary so you can store the values under a name/key.

Beware that adding the values to a collection might cost some time that could influence your measurements.

So you might want to do this:

```
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
get1(); 
stopwatch.Stop();
timings.Add("t1", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds); 
stopwatch.Start();
```

The finally is OK

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `List<long>` to store as many times as you need:

```
var times = new List<long>();
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
get1();
times.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
anotherGet();
times.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
vm.Detail = anotherAnotherGet();
times.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Putting your cleanup logic inside `finally` does not really do anything here because just before that you are unconditionally catching and swallowing all types of exceptions, **which is very very bad**.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm doing this only in the reporting code but I agree I missed handling the exceptions and I will add some code to do something if it falls into the exception block.  I was thinking finally always gets executed even if something falls into the catch so I stopped the stopwatch there. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: @Angela: No, that part is quite right. Most probably you should stop the timer inside `finally` and return the content after `finally` (only return content if no exception is thrown).

Answer (score 1):

You could store them in a `List<long>`

```
List<long> times = new List<long>();
```

And them simply

```
times.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: I might run the timing in different places. Is there a way I can declare times as a private at the top of my code and then clear the list each time it's run?